# Rank Function inside case statement

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to use Rank Function inside a case statement and give where rank_number = 1 , it's throwing error as unexpected where Condition. Can some one help me how to assign rank in where clause inside case statement

Comment: It's hard to say what the error is without any code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use the `RANK()` analytic function (or any other one, for that matter) in the `WHERE` clause of a query.  The results of the rank computation are not yet available.  But they are available in the `SELECT` clause or the `ORDER BY` clause.  One workaround would be to subquery:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY blah) rnk
    FROM yourTable t
) s
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Some databases support a `QUALIFY` clause, where it is possible to use analytic functions.  Assuming you are using something like Teradata or BigQuery, you could use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE 1 = 1
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (ORDER BY blah) = 1;
```